# AutoLISP - Change multiply layers by selecting multiply objects

Tags: autolisp

I'm trying to create a AutoLISP function that takes the selection sets layer and store it in a variable. 
I want to select multiply objects, which is allways in the same layer and then change the layer later with some commands.

I have tried the following, based on `(setq currentlayer (assoc  8 (entget (car (entsel)) )))`

My code is:

```
(defun c:objectslayer()
    (setq objects (car (ssget)))                    ; Need to select multiply objects
    (setq currentlayer (entget objects))            ; Need the layer of the objects, in my case, it will allways be in the same layer
    (setq cl (assoc 8 currentlayer))                ; Need the layer, for commands to change the layer later
    (prompt (strcat "\nThe layer of the objects is: " cl))
(princ)
)
```

I appreciate all the help and point of direction

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Without supplying a filter list argument to the `ssget` function, you cannot guarantee that all objects within the selection will reside on the same layer.

If you are targeting a specific layer with your program, then I would suggest using a filter list to only permit selection of objects residing on such layer, e.g.:

```lisp
(ssget '((8 . "YourLayerHere")))
```

Alternatively, you could prompt for selection of a single object to set the target layer (using `entsel`), and then prompt for a selection of multiple objects residing on such layer using `ssget` with a filter list constructed using the layer of the entity obtained from `entsel` e.g.:

```lisp
(if
    (and
        (setq ent (car (entsel "\nSelect object on target layer: ")))
        (setq sel (ssget (list (assoc 8 (entget ent)))))
    )
    (progn
        ;; Do some operations ...
    )
)
```

If you really want to permit the user to select objects on *any* layer, then to obtain a list of the layers selected, you could use something like:

```lisp
(defun c:test ( / idx lay lst sel )
    (if (setq sel (ssget))
        (progn
            (repeat (setq idx (sslength sel))
                (setq idx (1- idx)
                      lay (cdr (assoc 8 (entget (ssname sel idx))))
                )
                (if (not (member lay lst)) (setq lst (cons lay lst)))
            )
            (print lst)
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```

For more information on how to iterate over the objects in a selection set, you may wish to refer to my tutorial on [Selection Set Processing](http://lee-mac.com/selsetprocessing.html).

Comment: Great Explanation ... The way you use `(setq lst (cons lay lst))` instant of  `append` is impressive.

Comment: @DineshVilasPawar Thanks!